# Saving Dynamic Output when Closing

Tags: dynamic

I am using Dynamic to create a graph that continuously updates during a simulation. This allows my students to visually (1) confirm that the simulation is working and (2) to judge when the simulation has reached steady state. This all works fine. The problem is that the **graphical output is not saved when the file is closed**, which makes it more difficult for me (and the grader) to understand what was done.

As a simple example, consider the following code that outputs a sine wave with a time-varying phase:

```
phase = 0.0;
trigger = 0;
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[(trigger;
   ListPlot[Table[Sin[x + phase], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}], 
    Joined -> True]), TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}]] 
While[True,
 phase += Pi/100.;
 Pause[0.01];
 trigger++
 ]
```

When this file is saved and reopened without quitting Mathematica, everything is fine — I see the plot at the last plotted phase. If I quit Mathematica (or the kernel), then reopen the file, I see a blank graph.

The actual problem is, of course, more complicated than this and involves plotting a Table of atomic positions.

Comment: Just add   SaveDefinitions -> True as an option to `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: This only solves part of the problem. I would like the last state to be saved, not the first state. When I add SaveDefinitions->True, I get the first state.